# movie15 - embedded MP4 runs on some PDF viewers but not Adobe

Tags: beamer, embedding, adobe, movie15

I am working on a beamer presentation. In one of the frames i need to insert an MP4 video. I tried using the package movie15. I open this pdf in Adobe reader Version 2022.003.20310 and try to run the embedded video, however i keep getting this message "Acrobat has encountered an error while playing this media clip:" and couldn't run the video. However, in foxit Reader the embedded video runs so well, and even i have another version of adobe reader (Version 2022.003.20263) on another laptop, the video run so well there. I am curious to know how can i fix this issue on my current laptop, and know what is the reason of the current issue.

Below the code for the added embedded video:

```
\usepackage{movie15} 

\begin{frame}{:Motivation}
     \centering
    \includemovie[autoplay]{10cm}{8cm}{Figures/Ch0/M_demo_WithAnim_7.mp4}
\end{frame}
```

This question was posted before on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192234/embed-a-video-in-a-pdf-that-runs-on-adobe-reader-from-overleaf and reposted here because apparently it is Tex-latex issue.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should add links to all other versions in every version of your question! Otherwise you risk wasting both the time of users willing to help you as well as the time of users with the same problem who are searching for a solution.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75192234/2777074

Comment: In the short description for the package on ctan, it says that "The package is now superseded by media9". It seems to me that your problem is rather computer-based or OS-related, since the file works fine on other machines. The pdf version of movie15 is 1.5, and that of media9 is 1.7. Maybe your personal laptop is not fully compatible with ver. 1.5?

Comment: @tush how can i know with which versions my laptop is compatible? I have a windows 11

Comment: I don't know. Either way, it is not so muxh of a TeX.stackexchange question. Maybe try on stackoverflow.